# Xpath problem, getting the id(attribute) of a element, if you know the title of the element

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

This is my XML file, and i want to know how to get the ID of the article when you know
what the title is. Is this possible using Xpath?

XML file:

```
<Articles>
    <Article ID="1">
        <title>test</title>
        <content>test</content>
    </Article>
</Articles>
```

Php code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load("Articles.xml");
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$id = $xp->evaluate('string(/Articles/Article[title="test"]/@ID)');
var_dump($id);
```

Kind regards,

User.

Comment: Your for loop seems incomplete: `for($i = 0; $i title;`

Comment: There is no XML document here -- meaning that xml and xpath are not appropriate tags for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are using SimpleXml, you cannot return the ID directly. The correct XPath would be

```
/Articles/Article[title="crack"]/@ID
```

as shown elsewhere already. But SimpleXml has no concept of Attribute nodes. It only knows SimpleXmlElements. So you can just as well fetch the Article node instead

```
/Articles/Article[title="crack"]
```

because in the end you'll have to do the following to get the ID value anyway:

```
echo $articles[0]['id'];
```

Note that you do not need the @ when accessing the attribute from the SimpleXml Element.

If you wanted to fetch the ID attribute directly, you'd have to use DOM ([codepad](http://codepad.org/oZYy9JNI))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$id = $xp->evaluate('string(/Articles/Article[title="crack"]/@ID)');
var_dump($id);
```

The above would return 1 as long as there is no other node with a title element with a value equal to "crack".

In case you have nodes with formatting, [like shown in your screenshot](http://i53.tinypic.com/11hewjr.png), you have to sanitize the element before testing for the value. Otherwise the whitespace used to format the document is taken into account. The XPath for that would be

```
string(/Articles/Article[normalize-space(title) = "crack"]/@ID)
```

If you want to search for articles with a title that *contains* "crack" in part, use

```
string(/Articles/Article[contains(title, "crack")]/@ID)
```

Note that this will still only return the ID immediately as long as there is just one result. If there is multiple matching nodes, the first ID value will be returned. Use

```
/Articles/Article[contains(title, "crack")]/@ID
```

to return a DOMNodeList of all matching nodes and then iterate over them to get their individual ID values.

Also see the [basic usage examples for SimpleXml in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: I have tried using DOM but it isnt really working.
The var_dump gives me this "string(0) ", so does this mean there is a other node with the same value? cause this aint true.

Comment: @user no, it means the ID attribute is an empty string. I've added a link to codepad above. There you can see a full working script with the code snippet shown above. Also note that XML is case-sensitive, so id is not ID.

Comment: Ah lol i didnt see the link, i tested it, and it is indeed working. I replaced the $xml with this this->$dom->load('Articles.xml');, but that is not working. Is it possible to use an external XML document?

Comment: @user `load` is correct. I am not sure what you tried to there though. Unless you assigned the DOMDocument to a property, it's just $dom->load() and not $this->dom->load()

Comment: Yeah i tried $dom->load('Articles.xml'); not working :(
I cant believe this is not possible, just returning the value of the attribute of a node where the title is 'x'

Comment: @user It **is** possible. The code I gave you is working. You are doing something wrong. But unless you post a self contained example for us to review and reproduce no one can tell you what the issue is.

Comment: I know that the code you gave is working, but it is not possible when using an external xml file.

Comment: @user That's not true. The same code would work with an external file. Show your XML *and* your code. Then we can find your error.

Comment: Well what i did was replace the $dom->loadXML($xml); with
$dom->load('Articles.xml'); The xml document is the same but with more Article nodes in it.

Comment: @user I cannot help you if you don't [show your XML and your code](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4708304/edit)

Comment: @gordon Check my first post now.

Comment: @user Is it a typo or do you really have `</Articles><Articles>` in the XML? An XML file needs a root node. When you load the file, there should be errors with the XML you show (and of course it returns `string(0) ""` then. Without the additional `<Articles>` at the end, it will work fine. So if you have several articles in there make sure you have them inside a root node. Otherwise the XML is invalid.

Comment: @gordon, yeah it was a typo, i fixed it. But it isnt working though.

Comment: @user If the typo is not in it, you must be doing something else wrong. I am 100% sure this works for the shown code and XML. Are there any errors when you load the file? Put `error_reporting(-1)` on top of the file and make sure you display_errors enabled in your PHP.ini

Comment: @user if the XML shown in the screenshot is the XML in your Articles.xml it's not wonder that it cannot find anything. You are searching for crackerjack and none of the title elements contain that. And the XPath is different from the one we gave you.

Comment: Well i will upload a screenshot of the xml document too i guess.
The xml in the screenshot is not the same as the xml document.

Comment: @user I've updated my answer. You are testing for title elements with a node value *equal to* crackerjack. Your title elements contain whitespace from the formatting, e.g. your title element is "newline, lots of spaces, crackerjack, newline, lotsofspaces". Consequently, the XPath doesnt match the node.

Comment: Sir, you are my hero, next time i will be more clear about my problem. Because, we spent too much time solving this problem. Thank YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The path

```
/Articles/Article[title = "crack"]/@ID
```

should do it. You shouldn't have to iterate through the nodes.

Comment: I think you meant to write /Articles/Article[title="crack"]/@ID. But it's an odd question - it asks for an XPath solution, but doesn't seem to attempt to do it in XPath, instead using reams of unnecessary procedural PHP code.

Comment: Sir, thats why i asked. I asked for a xpath solution. I knew that the PHP code was unnecessary code, but i just couldnt figure out how to do it using xpath. Guess i need to study xpath more ;) Btw, the xpath you gave isnt really working.