# parsing xml id from website xml parser php

Tags: php, html, xml-parsing

I would like to parse the following id: `date`

How would I select it? I know how to select a class but I have had no luck for an id.

This is what I did with classes:

```
$xml->xpath('//*[@class="date"]');
```

I tried switching `@class` for `@id` but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

```
@$doc=new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html5);

$xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$images=$xml->xpath('//*[@id="date"]'); 
$arr= array();
foreach ($images as $img) {
  $arr[]= $img;
}

echo $arr[0];
```

Comment: Did you consider the Google or SO search function before you posted? This SO answer should help you out: [Xpath problem, getting the id(attribute) of a element, if you know the title of the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708304/xpath-problem-getting-the-idattribute-of-a-element-if-you-know-the-title-of)

Comment: Not following the example you posted, I asked because I was honestly struggling and could not find the answer but you seem to enjoy to take 10 seconds out of your day to bash me... thanks

Comment: very well, since you guilted me into it :) are you trying to parse out the single element in the DOM with an "id" attribute that equals "date"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you made me feel bad ...

The xpath query below will retrieve all elements that have the attribute id = date. Since you only care about the first one (there shouldn't be more than one because ID attributes are supposed to be unique ... but you never know), you need to reference `item(0)` in the `DOMNodeList` returned by the xpath query.

```
$xml = '<root><p>element we don\'t care about</p><p id="date">date element text</p></root>';
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
if ($el = $xpath->query("//*[@id='date']")->item(0)) {
  echo $el->nodeValue; // outputs: date element text
} else {
  echo 'no elements exist in the xml with an "id" attribute';
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I copied what you had exactly gave me an error stating I was trying to do it on an non object. I have edited my code to provide what I already have and maybe that will help. Thanks for attempting!

Comment: @Teddy13 The error you get from this code indicates that there is no element with the id `date`. You may want to add your xml to the question also.

Comment: @Yoshi is correct. **Your problem is that there are no elements with id attributes in whatever code you're parsing.** I've updated the code to allow for this behavior. My example deals with known XML source (this is why I included it) with an element containing an id attribute so it won't ever execute that conditional.